# Attempting to set height of UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to shrink the size of my UITextView (to 221 px) when the keyboard appears, and restore it to its normal height (337 px) when the keyboard disappears, so I did this:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = inkTextField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [inkTextField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [inkScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, inkTextField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
     inkTextField.frame=CGRectMake(1, -5, 285, 221);
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    inkScroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
    inkScroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    inkTextField.frame=CGRectMake(1, -5, 285, 337);
}
```

but this is not working. It's just using the height defined in the XIB file.

Comment: I wouldnt need to to do this had the original idea worked where it was just supposed to scroll as I type so that my text isn't hidden behind the keyboard. But it doesn't scroll up accuratly as I type. It's behind like 3 lines. I got this code from Apple but just added inkTextField.frame=CGRectMake... because the original didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok your code looks ok, have you checked if the code is even being run using `NSLog`? If that is the case then heres an easier method:
Create to `IBActions`:

```
- (IBAction)editBegan:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)editEnded:(id)sender;
```

Connect both `IBActions` with your textview. One with the connection `editingDidBegin` and the other one with `editingDidEnd` and in your .m simply put your code into each `IBAction` (the code for `keyboardWasShow`n into `editBegan` and the code for `keyboardWasDismissed` into `editEnded`)

Comment: keyboardWasShown has a (NSNotification*)aNotification variable that I need-how do I get that back with these new methods? And to what do I connect the text view to? I defined the two methods and implemented them, but I dont know how to connect them. All I see in the xib is Outlets, Referencing Outlets, Referencing Outlet Collections, and Received Actions, and none of them give me editBegan or editEnded

Comment: You should add the IBActions to the files owner class files. They are the class files with the same name as your nib. If you did that you should see the IBActions if you right click on the files owner oject in your nib. Also check if your is being run, add a NSLog(@"message"); into each implementation. If those messages appear in the debug console, then your code is being run.